# Looking for a Play Framework pagination example

Tags: java, playframework

I'm looking for a Play Framework pagination example. Please help me with a good reference link.

I searched for it and don't have java code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of pagination ?

Comment: Questions looking for an off-site resource are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Assume have 1000 records. Each page should display 10 records with next option, goto option etc., in Datatable

Comment: I provided a solution but please, next time improve your question by adding your own approach on how you tried to solve your problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide a Scala solution and you can adjust your code.

You could create a utility class called `Paginator`:

```
package util

case class Paginator[A](items: Seq[A], page: Int, offset: Long, total: Long) {
  lazy private val pageSize: Int = 20 // you can adjust to your preference
  lazy val prevPage: Option[Int] = Option(page - 1).filter(_ >= 0)
  lazy val nextPage: Option[Int] = Option(page + 1).filter(_ => (offset + items.size) < total)
  lazy val numberOfPages: Float = if (total % pageSize > 0) { total / pageSize + 1 }
                                  else { total / pageSize }
}
```

In your controller you will do something like:

```
def list(currentPage: Int) = Action.async { implicit request =>
  val offset: Int = currentPage * resultsPerPage

  // Put your logic here to get the `listOfItems` you want to display
  // and the number of `totalItems`

  // and then return Ok and call your view
  Ok(views.html.list(Paginator(listOfItems, currentPage, offset, totalItems)))
}
```

and finally in your view you will have something like:

```
@import util.Paginator

@(paginatedList: Paginator[Item])(implicit msg: play.api.i18n.MessagesProvider)

@main(msg.messages("label.list_of_items")) {
  <h1>@msg.messages("label.paginated_list")</h1>

  @* populate your list here *@

  @* and this is your paginator *@
  <div class="pagination">
    @paginatedList.prevPage.map { page =>
      <a href="@link(page)">@msg.messages("label.previous")<a>
    }.get
    @for(pageNumber <- 1 to paginatedList.numberOfPages.toInt) {
      <a href="@routes.Controller.list(pageNumber - 1)">@pageNumber</a>
    }
    @paginatedList.nextPage.map { page =>
      <a href="@link(page)">@msg.messages("label.next")</a>
    }.get
  </div>
}
```

I got the original idea from this [project](https://github.com/knoldus/playing-reactive-mongo.g8) and I've expanded on it. You can also improve the paginator by using `getOrElse` to provide alternative/disabled links when being on the first/last page, or to disable the current page number etc.

I hope this helps.